# Making a request to an API in php

Tags: php, api

So I want a way to start up and shutdown my droplet with Digital ocean, they have their own API but im not quite sure how to do it

basically I want to be able to click a button on my website, The server starts up and the JSON response is displayed. 
The API url is this https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/?client_id=[your_client_id]&api_key=[your_api_key]

and the example output is this:

{
  "status": "OK",
  "droplets": [
    {
      "id": 100823,
      "name": "test222",
      "image_id": 420,
      "size_id":33,
      "region_id": 1,
      "backups_active": false,
      "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
      "locked": false,
      "status": "active"
      "created_at": "2013-01-01T09:30:00Z"
    }
  ]
}

Any help is apreciated

EDIT: This is the code I'm trying to get to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Server Control Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Start!" name="submit" id="Startbutton" />
    <input type="submit" value="Stop Server" name "submit2" id"Stopbutton" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$request = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/377781/power_on/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE';
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
echo($response);                
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Stopbutton'])) {
$request = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/377781/shutdown/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE';
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
echo($response);                
}
echo("</ul>"); 

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problems you are experiencing exactly?

Comment: Well that no mater how I do it I cant get it it work.

Comment: Your problem is in your HTML. You have `name "submit2"` which should be with equal sign `name="submit2"` also, PHP testing should be on name field, no ID field: `if (isset($_POST['Stopbutton']))` $_POST['submit2'] is what you want. Good luck :)

Comment: Hmm okay I added that, it still didn't work.

Comment: Edit the code, so people can see other mistakes if present :)

Comment: Btw. start the debugging from the final. Does this link prints the proper json? https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/377781/shutdown/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE . If it does. Then you can test only getting the contents on it, without posting anything. Just blank PHP with file_get_contents("https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/377781/shutdown/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE"); If it's ok, then test the json_decode on it. And if it's ok again, we will search the problem in the IF statements. Otherwise it's in the API link

Comment: @Jasper: See the update in my answer below. That seems to be issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is missing `action` and `method` attributes. You might also want to rename the name attributes of your input fields to something more meaningful.

Here's the code with some improvements:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Startbutton'])) 
{
    $request = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/377781/startup/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE';
    $response  = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($jsonobj);       
    echo "</pre>";                 
}

if (isset($_POST['Stopbutton'])) 
{
    $request = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/377781/shutdown/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE';
    $response  = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($jsonobj);       
    echo "</pre>";        
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Server Control Panel</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Start!" name="Startbutton" id="Startbutton" />
    <input type="submit" value="Stop Server" name = "Stopbutton" id"Stopbutton" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

The issue seems to be with your API URL.

```
/droplets/377781/startup/client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE
```

should be:

```
/droplets/377781/startup/?client_id=CLIENTIDGOESHERE&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE
```

Notice the missing `?` after `/startup/`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: /droplets/[droplet_id]/shutdown is what im trying to use

Comment: Thank you so so much, I can not believe I missed that xD